# Where does PHPUnit Write the clover.xml to?

Tags: php, phpunit

Let's say I pass the following command to PHPUnit:

```
phpunit tests --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml
```

Where I can go to see the actual **clover.xml** file? I've looked everywhere, but I can't find it. I also can't find a **/build/logs** directory.

My tests run fine, as I see the following output: `Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.`

Answer (score 0):

The path you're passing: build/logs/clover.xml is relative to the current dir when you execute phpunit (because it does not start with / ).

If you want the path to be /build/logs/clover.xml, just add the slash to the command parameter:

```
phpunit tests --coverage-clover /build/logs/clover.xml
```